# Estrutura condicional e repetição For simples em C

Tags: c

Este é um código de estrutura condicional e repetição For simples em C. Porém, a saída está sendo a sequência: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20. Sendo que a saída esperada era uma sequência de 1 a 10 se fosse lido o número 1, ou uma sequência de 1 a 20 se fosse lido o número 2. Poderiam por favor me apontar o erro? Desde já obrigado!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c1,c2,ops;
    printf("Digite um opcao:");
    scanf("%d",&ops);
    if(ops=1)
    {
        for(c1=1;c1<=10;c1++)
           printf("%d ",c1);
    }
    if(ops=2)
    {
        for(c2=1;c2<=20;c2++)
           printf("%d ",c2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c1,c2,ops;
    printf("Digite um opcao:");
    scanf("%d",&ops);
    if(ops==1)
    {
        for(c1=1;c1<=10;c1++)
           printf("%d ",c1);
    }
    if(ops==2)
    {
        for(c2=1;c2<=20;c2++)
           printf("%d ",c2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Na condicional `if` ao colocar apenas um igual voce atribui esse valor, quando se coloca dois iguais (==) voce valida o valor, por exemplo `if(i == 1)` ou seja se `i` foi = a 1, caso esteja `if(i = 1)` voce está atribuindo esse valor logo o `i` vale 1. Entendeu?

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada, precisar estamos ai ;)

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi esclarecido, você usou o operador de atribuição `=` e não o de igualdade `==`. Erro comum, na verdade. Seja como for, escrevi um pequeno algoritmo para contribuir de alguma forma. ^_^

```
#define LC_CTYPE 2

// Protótipos
char* setlocale(int, const char*);
int printf(const char*, ...);
int scanf(const char*, ...);
int putchar(int);

int _cdecl main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "PtB"); // Para escrever em português do Brasil

    printf("Digite um número: ");
    unsigned int num = 0;

    if ((!scanf("%u", &num)) || (num != 1 && num != 2)) {
        printf("\nErro: digite um 1 ou 2.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned y = 0;

    if (num == 1) {
        y = 10;
    }
    else {
        y = 20;
    }

    putchar('\n');

    unsigned int x;
    for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
        printf("%u ", x);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Esse código é mais eficiente e completo porque utiliza iteração-*for* apenas uma vez. Além disso, possui um controle básico de erro, o que deveria fazer parte de qualquer programa, e contempla nossa linguagem, ao permitir acentos e coisas do tipo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]